# What are differences between wa.me and whatsapp://send?

Tags: whatsapp

I am a web developer. I found that there are two ways to make link to whatsapp, using wa.me (universal links) and whatsapp://send (Custom URL Scheme). But, what are the differences between that two ways?

References: https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/chats/how-to-use-click-to-chat/ and https://faq.whatsapp.com/android/im-an-android-developer-how-can-i-integrate-whatsapp-with-my-app/?lang=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whatsapp://send won't work on WA Web, only on the app, however, wa.me links will work on both WA Web and the app (that's why it is called universal link).